# how can i make this variable t global , so that it can be used in all functions

Tags: python, function, tkinter, global-variables

I am using `t` as global and assigned `t` value from the `s1`,`s2` functions
but after `person1` it is not going to `person2`. And the error is as below

```
File "C:\Users\Teja kaipa\Desktop\estimation.py", line 42, in person1
if (t>1):
    NameError: name 't' is not defined
global t
```

Code:

```
def s1():
    t=1
    return t
def s2():
    t=2
    return t
def s3():
    t=3

def person1():
    output = 0
    val1 = int(r1e1.get())
    val2 = int(r1w1.get())
    if ((val1-val2)==0):
        output = 1+2*val1
    else:
        output = -2*abs(val1-val2)
    r1n1m.delete(0, END)
    r1n1m.insert(4,str(output))    
    if (t>1):
        person2()

def person2():
    val1= int(r1e2.get())
    val2= int(r1w2.get())
    if ((val1-val2)==0):
        output = 1+2*val1
    else:
        output = -2*abs(val1-val2)
    r1n2m.delete(0, END)
    r1n2m.insert(4,str(output))    
    if (t>2):
        person3()
```

Comment: Yeah thanks , it does look abit similar. but i couldnt match it exactly as i started newly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside each module where you want to modify the global variable, explicitly specifying `t` as a global variable.

```
def func1():
    global t
    t = 3

def func2():
    global t
    t = [1,2,3]

def main():
    global t
    func1()
    print t
    func2()
    print t
```

The output should be:

```
3
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks bro, i am beginner . i am learning things online so i just missed some imp stuff. Thanks for the support :)